# Can't convert value to datetime from string

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

This is what I have written in .asp file..
it gives error like converting to date time....

```
<asp:TextBox ID="inputDate" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
 CssClass="inputDate regitextbox" value="06/14/2008"></asp:TextBox>
```

in cs file i wrote...

```
  var date = inputDate.Text.Trim();
  var da = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```

it gives following error..

> String was not recognized as a valid Date Time.

Comment: use datetime.parse();

Comment: You need to specify the culture to use for conversion.  Your system is probably running under a dd/MM/yyyy date system (such as en-GB), meaning "14" isn't a valid month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Parse(inputDate.Text.Trim());
```

Comment: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Above error appears

Comment: It didn't throw any error when I did `DateTime.Parse("06/14/2008");`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(inputDate.Text.Trim(), "M/dd/yyyy", enUS, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
   {
    //Action to use date;
   }
else
   {
    //action to tell user that inputDate.Text is not date string as expected
   }
```

Comment: This will try to parse text from input. If parse operation is successful TryParse will return TRUE and variable date will get DateTime representation of value in textbox inputDate. Otherwise TryParse  will return false and you can do some alert to user in else statement...